# Oracle SQL Updating Salary and Column Aliasing in a Select Query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having problems implementing code to perform a couple calculations and setting column aliases.

Situation description:

> The management wants to increase salary of all employees by 10%. Write a query to display empid, current salary, increased salary and incremented amount.

EmpId and Salary being existing columns in the table EmpDetails.

My Oracle SQL attempt:

```
SELECT
EmpId,
Salary AS 'Current Salary',
Salary*1.10 AS 'New Salary',
Salary*1.10-Salary AS 'Incremented Amount'
FROM EmpDetails
```

The output from my attempt is nothing. The interpreter doesn't support error messages and has issues displaying seemly valid code when it is incorrect for the problem for seemly any reason. This has left me confused while learning Oracle SQL syntax so the problem is likely the syntax in my attempt.

Is there way valid way to do this as a verbose select query like I attempted or maybe a simpler way for someone newer to SQL that uses multiple Alter/Update/Select commands?

Comment: Single quotes are for string literals, you can't use them for identifier names, such as column aliases.  As pointed out already in an answer, you'll need to use double quotes. Or better still, don't have spaces in your alias, that way you don't even need the double quotes at all.

Comment: Thanks! I think I accidently picked up single quote instead of double quote from http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp . As to spacing, I wish I could do without spaces but the interpreter that tests your solution in this ungraded course is extremely specific as to the correct answer.

Comment: A word of caution about w3schools.. not everything you read on there will work in an Oracle database. Syntax can vary between databases, and w3schools seems to mainly target SQL Server. Just something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

enclose the alias with double quote.

```
SELECT
EmpId,
Salary AS "Current Salary",
Salary*1.10 AS "New Salary",
Salary*1.10-Salary AS "Incremented Amount"
FROM EmpDetails
```

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for what turned out very tiny syntax error on my part. The ungraded course this is a part of only teaches very basic SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE queries and gives no insight into how to use operations like AS or anything else which seem necessary to perform the described assignments associated with the course.